# Почему в программе выводится лишняя строка? Как объекту присвоить имя?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Программа:

```
class Human:
    height = 0
    age = 0
    weight = 0
    intel = 0

    def __init__(self, height, age, weight, intel):
        self.height = height
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.intel = intel

    def character(self):
        print('Возраст - ' + str(self.age) + 'лет, его рост - ' + str(self.height) + ', вес - ' + str(self.weight)  + ', IQ - ' + str(self.intel))

Vanya = Human(186, 20, 80, 120) 
print(Vanya.character())
```

Вывод:

```
Возраст - 20лет, его рост - 186, вес - 80, IQ - 120
None
```

Почему выводится вторая строка `None`?
Как можно вывести имя объекта (в данном случае Vanya) без присваивания ее в методе `__init__`?

Comment: 2 раза принт. вот и 2 вывода. Vanya.character() возвращает в принт нон. и сам метод делает принт по формату.

Comment: Замени `print(Vanya.character())` на `Vanya.character()`

Comment: Что-то я устал похоже сегодня)

Comment: а с пробелами нет проблем ? вроде отступов нехватает. строки 2 3 4 5 можно не писать, их получаешь при вызове. и глядя на 2й вопрос, почему нельзя добавить self.name ? этож удобно

Comment: Не понял вопроса про пробелы.

Comment: после class Human(): должны идти отступы

Comment: Я просто хочу узнать нельзя ли как-нибудь вывести имя объекты без создания переменной self.name? То есть мы создаем экземпляр класса Human под названием Vanya. Нельзя ли как-нибудь вот это имя использовать?

Comment: У меня там стоят отступы, просто здесь так выводится

Comment: Что выведет вот эта строка: `print(Vanya.character())`

Comment: @MartinFlorense, `У меня там стоят отступы, просто здесь так выводится`, при добавлении кода ваша задача его форматировать, используйте *1)* `{}` на панели инструментов, выделив код *2)* или добавьте \`\`\` до и после кода, тогда он будет отформатирован и стилизирован

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выводится лишнее значение `None` в `print(Vanya.character())` потому что выводится значение функции `character`, а т.к. там ничего не возвращается, то и будет `None`.

Имя переменной получить можно, но вам не поможет, т.к. при `Vanya = Human("Ваня", 186, 20, 80, 120)` сначала создается объект `Human`, вызывается его конструктор, а после создается переменная `Vanya`, в которую поместится ссылка на объект `Human`.
Поэтому, рекомендую добавить имя вручную -- добавьте еще поле `name` и заполняйте его в конструкторе. Кст, для формирования строки с параметрами лучше использовать форматирование строк, чем ручным сложением строки.

Пример:

```
class Human:
    name = ''
    height = 0
    age = 0
    weight = 0
    intel = 0

    def __init__(self, name, height, age, weight, intel):
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.intel = intel

    def character(self):
        print(f'Имя - {self.name}, возраст - {self.age} лет, его рост - {self.height}, вес - {self.weight}, IQ - {self.intel}')

Vanya = Human("Ваня", 186, 20, 80, 120)
Vanya.character()
# Имя - Ваня, возраст - 20 лет, его рост - 186, вес - 80, IQ - 120
```

---

**PS.**

Для вашего случая рекомендую использовать декоратор `dataclass`, он создаст конструктор для заполнения полей, плюс проследит, чтобы их тип совпадал с указанным у полей.
Из бонуса он заполнит метод `__str__`, чтобы, например, при `print` объекта вывести все его поля в понятном виде:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Human:
    name: str
    height: int
    age: int
    weight: int
    intel: int

    def character(self):
        print(f'Имя - {self.name}, возраст - {self.age} лет, его рост - {self.height}, вес - {self.weight}, IQ - {self.intel}')

Vanya = Human("Ваня", 186, 20, 80, 120)
Vanya.character()
# Имя - Ваня, возраст - 20 лет, его рост - 186, вес - 80, IQ - 120

print(Vanya)
# Human(name='Ваня', height=186, age=20, weight=80, intel=120)
```